# Angular2 and typescript - how to add an array to a array from promise?

Tags: typescript, angular

In my controller, I make a rest call to create my table.  I need to append some fixed rows and I dont know how to do it.

I want something like this:

export class Environment {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

```
environments: any[]; 
production = new Environment('1', 'production');
development = new Environment('2', 'development');

    ngOnInit(){
            this.environmentService.getEnvironments()
                .subscribe(environments => this.environments = environments,null,() => { this.isLoading = false; });

        }
```

So how do I add an array to the promise result?"

```
  [this.production,this.development] + this.environments;
```

Results of proposed solution:

```
 staging: Environment = {
        id: '111',
        name: 'staging'
};

environments = [this.staging];

[ { "id": "111", "name": "staging" }, [ { "id": "86aa96e8-0383-4bce-b833-be3c21f47306", "name": "cloud" } ] ]
```

The name with cloud is from the server.  So close but should look like this:

```
[ { "id": "111", "name": "staging" },{ "id": "86aa96e8-0383-4bce-b833-be3c21f47306", "name": "cloud" } ]
```

This worked but is there a better way?:

```
this.environmentService.getEnvironments()
            .subscribe(environments => {
                for (var i = 0; environments.length > i; i++) 
                { this.environments.push(environments[i])}

            },null,() => { this.isLoading = false; });
```

Comment: Where's the promise result? Where's the array you want to add to?

Comment: From the the subscribe. environments => this.environments = environments

Comment: This question doesn't really have anything to do with TypeScript, Angular2 or Promises. As such, it should really be edited down to a simple question about how to combine two arrays in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Array.concat()`:

```
this.environmentService.getEnvironments()
  .subscribe(env => { this.environments = this.environments.concat(env); },
    null,
    () => { this.isLoading = false; }
  );
```